# Wild card in REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, regex, wildcard

I have data like this in a longtext column:

```
Name: Adam Smith
Name: Bob Johnson
Name: John Hansen
```

Is it possible to use a wildcard, within regexp? Say a user searches `Smith`, in pseudo-code:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE `file` REGEXP 'Name: %Smith%\n'
```

I'm pretty sure the `%` wildcard isn't a function within regexp. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why are you storing `Name: ` in each row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `REGEXP`-using answer is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `file` REGEXP 'Name: .*Smith.*\n'
```

However `LIKE` is more suitable:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `file` LIKE 'Name: %Smith%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (columnName) LIKE 'Name: %Smith%';`

Replace `(columnName)` as appropriate. Not clear if you meant `longtext` was the name of the column, but if it is, that's what you would replace it with.

Comment: i need to use regexp, not LIKE

Comment: Why? `LIKE` does exactly what you're asking for.